# Why enter (new line) will not exit from scanf?

Tags: c

Here is the program:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    int minx, x, y, z;

    printf("Enter four ints: ");
    scanf( "%i %i %i %i", &minx, &x, &y, &z);

    printf("You wrote: %d %d %d %d", minx, x, y, z);
}
```

Say if I enter like the following:   1 2 3 4 (then press <kbd>enter</kbd>).
The `scanf()` runs and reads the input buffer = 1 (space) 2 (space) 3 (space) 4 (space)(\n)
it reads until (\n) and \n will remain in the buffer.

If I enter like the following: 1 (then press <kbd>enter</kbd>) 2 (then press <kbd>enter</kbd>) 3 (then press <kbd>enter</kbd>) 4 (then press <kbd>enter</kbd>).
The `scanf()` runs and reads the input buffer = 1(\n)2(\n)3(\n)4(\n)(\n).

In those 2 cases, the `scanf()` skips the newline, whitespace and tries to read an `int`.

But if I enter 1 (then press <kbd>enter</kbd>)(then press <kbd>enter</kbd>)... the `scanf()` then never runs if I keep hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.

My question is: what triggers `scanf()`? Will it only run after it knows all the correct `%d` are placed in the buffer then run if the user press enter?

Comment: The stdio.h include should be <stdio.h>

Answer (score 4):

Because `scanf()` ignores white space, and white space includes newlines.

The `scanf()` processes the four numbers the same way each time: by skipping white space, then reading a candidate sequence that looks like a number (so signs and digits), and stops reading at the first character that can't be part of the candidate sequence; it then converts the candidate sequence (behaviour on overflow etc undefined).  If you typed a space after the `4` (rather than just a newline), both the space and the newline will still be waiting to be read next.  If there's no space, then the newline will be waiting to be read.

If you typed a non-numeric character (punctuation or letter), then `scanf()` would return with an error (or fewer than 4 numbers converted — unless the letter is after the fourth number).

When you type a single number followed by an arbitrary number of newlines, you're simply giving `scanf()` white space to skip over.  It won't stop until it gets EOF (zero bytes read) or a read error (or a conversion error, such as a letter or punctuation character instead of a digit).

Comment: Thank for your time.
Ignore? then why newlines will trigger scanf if all the %d are entered?

Comment: @qwrqwr: that's not scanf, but the kernel tty driver which is line oriented (it won't send the data to your program until you press enter or ^D)

Answer (score 1):

that is the expected behaviour of scanf
From the c99 standard:

A conversion specification is executed in the following steps:
   -   Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a '[', 'c', or 'n' specifier.

it tokenises on the seperator characters (space tab newline etc ..)
the last newline is part of the tokenisation .. otherwise how would it know when your integer finishes? :D

I think this solves your question? i am not sure . Hope this helps